# Attract objects around given point without overlapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, game-physics, particles

I have a number of objects that I want to be attracted towards another object. These objects should arrange around that target object and not overlap each other, so that they create like a random cloud around that object without intersecting it.

Currently I have the following code for every object, but the problem is that the objects overlap each other. How can I avoid overlapping?
I suppose my "move towards target" solution is too simple for this?

```
const float minDistance = 600.0f;
Vector2 dir = Vector2.Normalize(targetPos - this.pos);
float dist = Vector2.Distance(targetPos, this.pos);

targetPosition = BasePosition + dir * (dist - minDistance);

[OnUpdate]
this.pos = Vector2.Lerp(this.pos, targetPosition, deltaTime);
```

Comment: You may use `+=`, not `=`

Comment: you are actually right, but I am lerping the position so i dont need +=
I have updated the code above.

Comment: You need to have some kind of collision detection and possibly a repelling potential, acting at very close proximity, for the big object and all the smaller objects.